# Looping over objects in array and adding property to each

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I'm getting an array of files, and then I want to add the date and size properties to each of those file objects, but using the code below, they don't get added. I know that's my `fs.statSync(p + file).mtime.getTime()` and `fs.statSync(p + file).size` have values in them.

```
var files = fs.readdirSync(p);

files.sort(function(a, b) {
           return fs.statSync(p + a).mtime.getTime() - 
                  fs.statSync(p + b).mtime.getTime();
});

files.forEach(function(file) {
    file.date = fs.statSync(p + file).mtime.getTime();
    file.size = fs.statSync(p + file).size;
});

console.log('files::'+files); // doesn' have the new file.date and file.size property.
```

Comment: is it giving some error?

Comment: no its just not adding the new properties. The array stays in the same form as when it started.

Comment: What if you log in the foreach-callback? Have you tried file['date']?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to Eugene's answer, but this uses [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
files = files.map(function(file) {
  file.date = fs.statSync(p + file).mtime.getTime();
  file.size = fs.statSync(p + file).size;
  return file;
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gZ8Vu/)

Answer (score 3):

When you writing value into `file` variable it's not saving because `file` it's variable that lives into local scope. So a quick solution for this:

```
var files = fs.readdirSync(p),
    result = [];

files.sort(function(a, b) {
           return fs.statSync(p + a).mtime.getTime() - 
                  fs.statSync(p + b).mtime.getTime();
});

files.forEach(function(file) {
    file.date = fs.statSync(p + file).mtime.getTime();
    file.size = fs.statSync(p + file).size;
    result.push(file);
});

console.log('files::' + result);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `file` variable is a local variable. Without having to create a new array as Eugene did, you can update the original array in this way:

```
var files = fs.readdirSync(p);

files.sort(function(a, b) {
           return fs.statSync(p + a).mtime.getTime() - 
                  fs.statSync(p + b).mtime.getTime();
});

files.forEach(function(file, index, array) {
    array[index].date = fs.statSync(p + file).mtime.getTime();
    array[index].size = fs.statSync(p + file).size;
});

console.log('files::'+files);
```